# export from php to csv as a stream

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, pdo

I have a website that is pulling data from a MSSQL DB and exporting it to a csv. The problem I'm having is that it's pulling all the data and running out of memory. Error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 805 bytes) in D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\ExportToExcel.php on line 94`

Is there a way to stream the data instead of pulling it all to memory? here's how I'm doing it now:

```
$getqueries = $conn->query($tsql);
//$result = $getqueries->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$filename = $_POST['ExportToExcel'];

header("Content-Type: application/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");

$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings; $i++)
{
    $headings[] = $rHeadings[$i]["Headings"];
}

foreach($headings as $Heading => $value)
{
    echo "$value" . $sep;
}
//end of printing column names
echo $br;
$l = 0;
foreach($getqueries->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
        $pos = strpos($row,$sep);
        $CommentPos = strpos($rHeadings[$l]["Headings"],"comment");
        $NewLines = array("\r\n","\n\r","\n","\r");
        $UseValue = str_replace($NewLines, " ",$row);
        if($pos === FALSE)
        {
            if($CommentPos === FALSE)
            {
                echo $UseValue . $sep;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '"' . $UseValue . '"' . $sep;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '"' . $UseValue . '"' . $sep;
        }
        $l++;
}
```

It's not that big a file, ends up being less than 20mb, my server just can't seem to handle it. I have looked around, but I've not seen anything that addresses my exact problem.

Comment: Simple solution: Instead of `fetchAll()` you could use `fetch()` and write each row to the CSV file one by one. But considering that you used 134 MB before you ran out of memory there might be another problem in your code. I cannot tell because your code is incomplete. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is fetchAll() the only PDO method you know?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, `fetchALL()` is the only one that I know. I'm pretty new to php and pdo.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the solution to the duplicate doesn't work for me, it was in MYSQL I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: Well, don't be afraid to learn. [there are other ways to get your data in a loop](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach) without memory overhead.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The link you sent didn't work?

Comment: [It's just you. http://phpdelusions.net is up.](http://www.isup.me/phpdelusions.net)

Comment: But Ok, here is another http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#example-1039

Comment: @YourCommonSense that one works, idk what's up with the other. I can pull it up on my tablet, but not on my computer.

Comment: either way, don't use fetchAll, don't use for(). Use $getqueries itself in the foreach().

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have switched to using `fetch()`, but i'm not sure I'm doing it right as I only get one row, the `foreach` loops through the columns in only the first row. How do I get it to go through all rows? I've updated the code above. Or should I just ask a new question?

Comment: **foreach($getqueries as $row)**

Comment: @YourCommonSense then where do I put the `fetch()`? I thought that is what would be in the `foreach()` like `foreach($getqueries->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)`

Comment: nowhere you have to put it. did you see the code I posted above?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I saw it, that's why I was asking. I think I've almost got it working. I'll add the completed code to the question when finished.

Comment: Additionally you can have PHP create the CSV formatting for you - it will automatically add quotations when needed and commas: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#72428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem I had with not enough memory by not using `fetchALL()`:

```
$tsql = "Select Id,State,ProjectNumber,SubProjectNumber,PONumber
            from pmdb.MaterialTracking order by State,ProjectNumber";
$hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'MaterialTracking' 
         and Headings != 'Edit' order by ID";

$filename = $_POST['ExportToExcel'];

header("Content-Type: application/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

//define separators (defines columns in excel)
$sep = ",";
$br = "\r\n"; //line break

$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$headings = array();
$NumHeadings = count($rHeadings);

for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings; $i++)
{
    $headings[] = $rHeadings[$i]["Headings"];
}
//start of printing column names as names of SQL fields
foreach($headings as $Heading => $value)
{
    echo "$value" . $sep;
}
//end of printing column names
echo $br; //separate the headers and the data

foreach($conn->query($tsql) as $row)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i < $NumHeadings;$i++)
    {
        $CommentPos = strpos($rHeadings[$i]["Headings"],"comment");
        $NewLines = array("\r\n","\n\r","\n","\r");
        $UseValue = str_replace($NewLines, " ",$row[$i]);
        $UseValue = str_replace('"', "'",$row[$i]);
        $pos = strpos($UseValue,",");
        if ($CommentPos === FALSE || $pos === FALSE || isset($UseValue))
        {
            echo '"' . $UseValue . '"' . $sep;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $UseValue . $sep . "Not quoted";
        }
    }
}
```

There are actually 39 columns in this table, and a total (today at least) of 39812 rows. This gives me the csv that I need.